# Can I add a certificate template type to the "Submit a Certificate Request" page in AD CS Web Enrollment?

Tags: ad-certificate-services

In the CA Web Enrollment website, on the "Submit a Certificate Request or Renewal Request" page (`https://<servername>/certsrv/certrqxt.asp`) there is a dropbox under the "Certificate Template:" section with values for various certificate template types. I have a custom template that I would like to issue a cert for; how can I get that particular template name to be added to this list, or is it pre-defined by Microsoft and unchangeable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one answered and I needed an answer to this one, bucked up and opened a per-incident support ticket with MSFT Support. Per MSFT Support, the Web Enrollment "Certificate Template" dropbox is NOT extensible. It's designed to be a simple way to request/recieve User and Web Server certificates.

I have to use `certlm.msc` (Certificate Management for Local Machine), right-click on Personal > Certificates, and choose "All Tasks > Request New Certificate" to be able to choose my custom template. Once the certificate is issued (lands in the Local Machine's Personal Certificates folder) you can then export it as a .pfx, use the .pfx to install the cert to the target machine (don't forget to mark the private key as exportable when you request the cert!) and then delete the already-exported cert out of the local machine's cert store. Ugly, but it works...